# jQuery - Replace all parentheses in a string

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

I tried this:

```
mystring= mystring.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
```

It works for all double and single quotes but for parentheses, this only replaces the first parenthesis in the string.

How can I make it work to replace all parentheses in the string using JavaScript? Or replace all special characters in a string?

Comment: This isnt jQuery, its just standard javascript

Comment: oops! hope you understand the requirement, i need to get this done either by jquery or standard javascript. would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try the following:

```
mystring= mystring.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
```

A little bit of REGEX to grab those pesky parentheses.

Answer (score 30):

You should use something more like this:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/["'()]/g,"");
```

The reason it wasn't working for the others is because you forgot the "global" argument (g)

note that `[...]` is a character class.  anything between those brackets is replaced.

Comment: Do you not need to escape the parentheses?

Comment: @MattFellows not while it's in a character class. (I tend to put special characters in character classes just so I don't have to escape them... makes it more readable for me at least :P)

Comment: @MattFellows I will add however that the exceptions to this are `[`, `]`, and `\\` which do need escaped.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I learn something new every day, thanks! I had no clue you don't have to escape them.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do this in a single replace statement.

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/["'\(\)]/g, "");
```

If you're trying to replace all *special* characters you might want to use a pattern like this.

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\W/g, "");
```

Which will replace any non-word character.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a regular experession if you're looking for parenthesis, you just need to escape them.

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
```

This will remove all `(` and `)` in the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

Just one replace will do:

```
"\"a(b)c'd{e}f[g]".replace(/[\(\)\[\]{}'"]/g,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work :

```
mystring= mystring.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(/g, "").replace(/\)/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because to replace multiple occurrences you must use a regex as the search string where you are using a string literal. As you have found searching by strings will only replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The string-based replace method will not replace globally. As such, you probably want to use the regex-based replacing method. It should be noted:

You need to escape `(` and `)` as they are used for group matching:

```
mystring= mystring.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(/g, "").replace(/\)/g, "");
```

Comment: But there's no concept of "group" for the non-regex version of `replace` that the OP is using.

Comment: That is true - but to get global replacing you need to use a regex I believe - hence why I've sugested a regex, and then my statement is true.

Comment: It's true, but it's just a bit misleading IMO since the grouping issue was not the cause of the OP's original problem. I just think it's worth a specific mention that you're converting his string-based `replace`s to regex-based `replace`s.

Comment: Duly noted updating to make it explicit

Answer (score 0):

This can solve the problem:
`myString = myString.replace(/\"|\'|\(|\)/)`
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xztf5ers/)