# Inner html replace with text in brackets

Tags: html

I am able to replace this text -->>

`"querying policy failed: No such file or directory"` fine to `"HELLO"`.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /querying policy failed: No such file or directory /g,
    "<span style='color:black;background-color:#ABB2B9'>HELLO</span>")
```

But I want to replace this text -->> `"querying policy failed: No such file or directory (2)"`, which is not happening due to text in brackets -> (2).

Below code doesnt work.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /querying policy failed: No such file or directory (2)/g,
    "<span style='color:black;background-color:#ABB2B9'>HELLO</span>")
```

Any suggestions , how to replace

`querying policy failed: No such file or directory (2)` to `HELLO`.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Please add quotes around your code like ` `<your code here>` ` .

Comment: get rid of regex, just use .replace() as string-to-string https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape the parenthesis by inserting `\` before them, as they are reserved characters used for capturing groups.

You can learn more about RegExp capturing groups in [Groups and ranges - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) and about character escaping in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript).

```js
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML.replace(/querying policy failed: No such file or directory \(2\)/g, '<span style="color: black; background-color: #ABB2B9">HELLO</span>');
```

```html
<p>querying policy failed: No such file or directory (2)</p>
```

Comment: Nice. Now sure why it was not working yesterday. i think i tried that way. But still you solved the issue. thanx

Answer (score 0):

```js
// escape the parentheses with backslashes directly in the string.
//document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
//    /querying policy failed: No such file or directory \(2\)/g,
//    "HELLO");

// in two steps. 
// 1. remove the parens; 
// 2. remove the rest of the string.
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
    .replace(/[()]/g, "")
    .replace(/querying policy failed: No such file or directory 2/g, "HELLO");
```

```html
querying policy failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9115461/1171702